# Python telegram bot: how to distinguish a user with hidden profile?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I have a feedback bot that forwards messages from users to a group chat of admins. Admins reply to a message and the bot sends their response back to the person it received the message from.

Telegram has a privacy setting to disable linking a forwarded message to users' account:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqLPY.png)

In this case, the bot is unable to send back the response. I would like to detect that a person has a hidden account and warn them that they won't get a response. I can't seem to figure out what method/property could give me that information.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to keep track of which user message originated which message in the admin chat rather than relying on the `message.forward_from` attribute. Since you tagged the `python-telegram-bot` library, let my point you to [this thread on GitHub](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/1934) which has the same topic.

Comment: Thanks :) ig it's even better that way, users don't need to care about their privacy settings and will still get a reply